# How to enable all RDS traffic from cloudFormation file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

I would like to connect to the database using MysqlWorkbench.
I'm using serverless framework. I want to automate the creation of rds, but I want the created rds to have all the traffic open. How to do it from *.yml file?
I don't want to use aws console.
Is there any easy way to automate this?

*part of the serverless.yml file*

```
resources:
  Resources:
    DatabaseCluster:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
      Properties:
        DatabaseName: name${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
        Engine: aurora
        MasterUsername: ${ssm:MasterUsername-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}}
        MasterUserPassword: ${ssm:MasterUserPassword-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}}
        Port: "3306"

    ServerlessRDS:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      Properties:
        Engine: aurora
        DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref "DatabaseCluster"
        DBInstanceIdentifier: db-name-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
        DBInstanceClass: db.t2.medium
```

Comment: Short answer: Bastion Host. There's a decent explanation here: https://interworks.com.mk/managing-your-aws-rds-instance-via-bastion-host/

With this, you can create the EC2 and other components necessary by using the CF template.

I can't post a clearer answer right now (and exemplify with the CF template), but if no one has an answer until tomorrow, I will make sure I post one here :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, Guilerme's link is great.
To summarize what is needed in your .yml file, you will have to create the following resources:

1. Create a security group (`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`) for your EC2 instance in the same VPC, under the same resource define `SecurityGroupIngress` that will allow access to SSH TCP port 22 from your (or all) IP, and `SecurityGroupEgress` to your RDS instance with port 3306 (Please note that the guide talks about port 5432 in case of PostgreSQL)
2. Edit the security group of the RDS (`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress`) to enable access to port 3306 for the security group we've just created
3. Create the EC2 instance for the Bastion Host (`AWS::EC2::Instance`), make sure it is on a public subnet. Regarding the key, I don't know if it's possible to a create a new key resource with the Template file, I personally do it manually.
4. Create and attach an Elastic IP (`AWS::EC2::EIP`) to this EC2 instance

After the creation of these resources, you will be able to connect to your RDS using the Bastion Host.

Hope I didn't forget anything. Good luck!